# Deleting blank fields in multiple shapefiles in folder using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, null

I have some shapefiles and each shapefile is having some blank or zero value fields. My task is to delete blank/zero value  fields for all shapefiles in the folder. I have searched for solution in this site and found one Python program but unfortunately I am not successful with available Python program. Below is the my code and I don't know where I made a mistake.

I have attached image also for reference and the fields i wanted to delete are shown with line

After running code, I did not encounter any error message but fields are not removed

result:

> > > ```
> > > Empty field deleted
> > > ```

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
path = r"C:\SOFTWARE\Shapefiles\test"
env.workspace = path
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()  

# Iterate over the feature classes
for fc in fcs:
    # Test whether the field is required--rather than testing the field type
    fieldList = arcpy.arcpy.ListFields(fc)

    # Iterate over the fields
    for field in fieldList:
        # Set a test variable to False
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, field.name) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:`enter code here`
                if field == " " or field == 0:
                    arcpy.DeleteField_management(fc, field.name)
print ("Empty field deleted")
```

[image]

Comment: The definition of a *blank field* in dBase is subject to debate, since .dbf predates numeric or string nulls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list of fields per feature class. Next iterate through each table and check each attribute for value. If an attribute has a value add the field to a list of keep field. Any field that doesn't appear in the keep field list can be deleted.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
path = r"C:\SOFTWARE\Shapefiles\test"
env.workspace = path
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()  

# Iterate over the feature classes
for fc in fcs:
    print fc
    print "listing fields"
    flds = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields (fc)]
    print "iterating table"
    #set of fields to keep
    keepFlds = set ()
    #number of fields
    fldCount = len (flds)
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (fc, flds) as curs:
        for row in curs:
            for i in range (fldCount):
                #check if field has value
                if not row [i] in ("", 0, None):
                    keepFlds.add (flds [i])

    #delete fields
    for fld in flds:
        if not fld in keepFlds:
            print "deleting field", fld
            arcpy.DeleteField_management (fc, fld)
```

Comment: Hi @Emil Brundage.Thank you for sharing code. With your code I can delete all fields with value "0" deleting but can't delete empty fields(nothing in that) without any attributes.                 Task1. delete all fields with zero value (it is working with your code)                                                 2.Also I want to delete other empty fields without attributes. Can you help me to fulfill my task

Comment: This code should work in either case. Maybe your field has a single space? `" "`

Comment: Hi Emil Brundage, as per your suggestion, I have checked fields for spaces. They are empty fields without any attributes even no spaces. More ever  I have added some empty fields without any spaces and run code but empty fields are not deleted and they are remains same. Any suggestion/idea regarding code?

Comment: I’ve tweaked the code a bit @Arb . See how that does.

Comment: Oh it is working now. small issue is code deleting fields only for the first shape file and not deleting fields for further shape files in the same folder. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not currently able to test this but here are some issues I can see:

You need to loop through every record in every field to check that they are all blank or `0`. Once you have looped through these you can then delete the field.

You should create a list of fields to delete (once looped to verify) and then use `DeleteField()` only once after the cursor is complete. This would allow for 2 things, 1) reduce potential for the cursor to break if you delete a field, and 2) you can the output the list of fields rather than actually deleting to help test/debug your script

Something like this (note this is **untested**):

```
for fc in fcs:
    fieldList = arcpy.arcpy.ListFields(fc)
    fieldsToDelete = list() #Create a list of fields to delete at the end

    for field in fieldList:
        deleteField = False #Only delete fields with deleteField = True
        valCount = 0 #Count the number of "non-blank" values
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, field.name) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                if row[0] is None or row[0] in ["", " ", 0]:
                    valCount += 0
                else:
                    valCount =+ 1
                    break #No need to continue if a value is found
                if valCount == 0:
                    deleteField = True #If no values found, mark the field for deletion

        if deleteField == True:
            fieldsToDelete.append(field.name) #Add the field name to list of fields to delete

    print fieldsToDelete #Output the list of fields that will be deleted
    # Uncomment the line below once you are happy the correct fields will be deleted
    # arcpy.DeleteField_management(fc, fieldsToDelete) #Delete blank fields
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach that uses a generator to identify delete fields:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\temp\test.gdb'

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
    for field in fields:
        vals = set(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, field.name)) # Generate a unique list of values in field
        if any(map(lambda each: each in vals, [0, '0',' ', '', None])) and len(vals) == 1: # Check if field is of length = 1 and contains search characters
            arcpy.DeleteField_management(fc, field.name)
```

---

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]